# Proving that a continuous map is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map such that $\overline{f(\mathbb{N})} = \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

I tried to use the definition of the continuity and $\overline{f(\mathbb{N})} = \mathbb{R}$ to show that $f$ is surjective but it didn't work. Since $f$ is continuous, the preimage of every open set is open. Also it results in $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$ for every set $A$. How this couples with $\overline{f(\mathbb{N})} = \mathbb{R}$ to show surjectivity?

Comment: I think this exact question was asked earlier this day, but anyways it follows from the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in\Bbb R$; you want to prove that $x=f(y)$, for some $y\in\Bbb R$. Since $x+1\in\overline{f(\Bbb N)}$, $x+1$ is the limit of a sequence of numbers of the form $f(n_k)_{k\in\Bbb N})$, where each $n_k$ is a natural number. In particular, there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)>x$. By the same argument, there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(m)<x$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $y$ between $m$ and $n$ such that $f(y)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $b \in \mathbb R$. By hypothesis, it exists $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that
$f(a_1) \in (b-3/2, b-1/2)$ and $f(a_2) \in (b+1/2, b+3/2)$.

Then by the intermediate value theorem, it exists $a \in (a_1, a_2)$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Thanks. Why hypothesis implies that it exists $a_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a_1) \in (b-3/2, b-1/2)$?

Comment: Because $\overline{f(\mathbb N)}=\mathbb R$ means that $f(\mathbb N)$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, i.e. that $f(\mathbb N) \cap I \neq \emptyset $ for any non empty open interval $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How do you prove that $f$ takes all values between $0$ and $1$ if it takes the value $0$ and $1$?